# Importing Your Own Module Python Attribute Error

Tags: python-2.7, module, python-import

so I am trying to import my own python module into a new script that I have written. I get the error:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getSessionIds'

In my main file, I am importing as such:

```
import UnityAppSessionSummary

class ScheduledGenSummaries(DatabaseModule): 
   def __init__(self):
       super(ScheduledGenSummaries, self).__init__()
   def run(self):
       ... (some db connection stuff)
       sessionIds = UnityAppSessionSummary.getSessionIds(db, user)

if __name__ == '__main__':
       testrun = ScheduledGenSummaries()

       testrun.run()
```

In my UnityAppSessionSummary.py file, I have something as such:

```
class UnityAppSessionSummary():
    # This method is used to obtain a list of all session ID's for a certain user
    def getSessionIds(self, db, user):
        ....code....
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error and I have looked at other previous posts. I have tried 'import UnityAppSessionSummary as app' and then app.(some function in UnityAppSessionSummary), but it still gives me the error. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have a file `UnityAppSessionSummary.py` that is being imported when you run

```
import UnityAppSessionSummary
```

However, inside that `.py` file you have a class named `UnityAppSessionSummary` as well, and inside **that** is your `getSessionIds()` method. Try this:

```
from UnityAppSessionSummary import UnityAppSessionSummary as app

# ...
sessionIds = app.getSessionIds(db, user)
```

Comment: I next get an error: TypeError: unbound method getSessionIds() must be called with UnityAppSessionSummary instance as first argument (got Database instance instead)

Does that mean I need to add a super(UnityAppSessionSummary, self).getSessionIds() to my file 'UnityAppSessionSummary.py'?

Comment: @ajl123 No. Instead, you need to create an instance of your class, then call `getSessionIds()` on that instance. So, `my_app = app(args); my_app.getSessionIds(db, user)`